# Delete rows having opposite values and first in sequence and leave rest with opposite value

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am new to the  SQL Server. Can someone help me please.
I have a situation where I need to delete the rows where the sum of the two rows of Rate column is zero under same Parent id. For Example I Need to delete the rows id = 9 and 10 because the sum of rate against these rows is zero. -20.24 + 20.24 = 0
These are extra rows making report larger.
I want to delete the following rows where:

```
    ****Parent id = 77 id = 9 and 10
    Parent id = 88 id = 11 and 12
    Parent id = 99 id = 14 and 15
    Parent id = 110  id = 18  and 19
    Parent id = 111  id = 22 and 23****


    declare @testtable table (id int, PARENTID int, ENTRYDATE DATETIME, NAME VARCHAR(50), RATE NUMERIC(10, 2), ENDDATE VARCHAR(50), STATUS VARCHAR(50))

        insert into @testtable values
         (1,    11, '1/3/2017', 'TEST',     0.07,       '',             'NEW')
        ,(2,    22, '1/12/2017','TEST1',    -43.24,     '1/12/2017',    'TERM')
        ,(3,    33, '1/9/2017', 'TEST2',    -45.17,     '1/6/2017',     'TERM')
        ,(4,    44, '1/4/2017', 'TEST3',    1,          '',             'NEW')
        ,(5,    55, '1/3/2017', 'TEST4',     -32.54,    '1/2/2017',     'TERM')
        ,(6,    55, '1/24/2017','TEST5',     30.74,     '',             'NEW')
        ,(7,    66, '1/6/2017', 'TEST6',     11.56,     '',             'NEW')
        ,(8,    66, '1/19/2017','TEST7',    -7.56,      '1/6/2017',     'TERM')
        ,(9,    77, '1/18/2017','TEST8',    -20.24,     '1/20/2017' ,   'TERM')
        ,(10,   77, '1/19/2017','TEST9',    20.24,      '',             'NEW')
        ,(11,   88, '1/3/2017', 'TEST10',   -4.25,      '1/3/2017',     'TERM')
        ,(12,   88, '1/5/2017', 'TEST11',   4.25,       '',             'NEW')
        ,(13,   88, '1/5/2017', 'TEST12',   -4.25,      '1/3/2017',     'TERM')
        ,(14,   99, '1/5/2017', 'TEST13',   -19.15,     '1/2/2017'  ,   'TERM')
        ,(15,   99, '1/16/2017','TEST14',   19.15,      '',             'NEW')
        ,(16,   99, '1/16/2017','TEST15',   -19.15,     '1/16/2017',    'TERM')
        ,(17,   99, '1/24/2017','TEST16',   19.15,      '',             'NEW')
        ,(18,   110,    '1/5/2017', 'TEST17',   -21.86,     '1/2/2017'  ,   'TERM')
        ,(19,   110,    '1/5/2017', 'TEST18',   21.86,      '',             'NEW')
        ,(20,   110,    '1/16/2017','TEST19',   -21.86,     '1/16/2017',    'TERM')
        ,(21,   110,    '1/16/2017','TEST20',   21.86,      '',             'NEW')
        ,(22,   1111,   '1/11/2017','TEST21',   -7.36,      '12/30/2016',   'TERM')
        ,(23,   1111,   '1/13/2017','TEST22',   7.36,       '',             'NEW')
        ,(24,   1111,   '1/13/2017','TEST23',   -7.36,      '1/13/2017' ,   'TERM')
        ,(25,   1111,   '1/18/2017','TEST24',   8.14,       '',             'NEW')


select * from @testtable

id  PARENTID ENTRYDATE  NAME    RATE    ENDDATE    STATUS
1     11    1/3/2017    TEST    0.07                NEW
2     22    1/12/2017   TEST1   -43.24  1/12/2017   TERM
3     33    1/9/2017    TEST2   -45.17  1/6/2017    TERM
4     44    1/4/2017    TEST3    1                  NEW
5     55    1/3/2017    TEST4   -32.54  1/2/2017    TERM
6     55    1/24/2017   TEST5   30.74                NEW
7     66    1/6/2017    TEST6   11.56                NEW
8     66    1/19/2017   TEST7   -7.56   1/6/2017    TERM
9     77    1/18/2017   TEST8   -20.24  1/20/2017   TERM
10    77    1/19/2017   TEST9   20.24                NEW
11    88    1/3/2017    TEST10  -4.25   1/3/2017    TERM
12    88    1/5/2017    TEST11  4.25                NEW
13    88    1/5/2017    TEST12  -4.25   1/3/2017    TERM
14    99    1/5/2017    TEST13  -19.15  1/2/2017    TERM
15    99    1/16/2017   TEST14  19.15               NEW
16    99    1/16/2017   TEST15  -19.15  1/16/2017   TERM
17    99    1/24/2017   TEST16  19.15               NEW
18    110   1/5/2017    TEST17  -21.86  1/2/2017    TERM
19   110    1/5/2017    TEST18  21.86               NEW
20   110    1/16/2017   TEST19  -21.86  1/16/2017   TERM
21   110    1/16/2017   TEST20  21.86               NEW
22   1111   1/11/2017   TEST21  -7.36   12/30/2016  TERM
23   1111   1/13/2017   TEST22  7.36                NEW
24   1111   1/13/2017   TEST23  -7.36   1/13/2017   TERM
25   1111   1/18/2017   TEST24  8.14                NEW
                       **TOTAL    -88.61**
```

The result should be like following.
Total of rate column will have no impact. It is same.

```
id  PARENTID ENTRYDATE       NAME       RATE      ENDDATE     STATUS
1     11        1/3/2017      TEST      0.07                    NEW
2     22        1/12/2017     TEST1    -43.24    1/12/2017      TERM
3     33        1/9/2017      TEST2    -45.17     1/6/2017      TERM
4     44        1/4/2017      TEST3      1                      NEW
5     55        1/3/2017      TEST4    -32.54     1/2/2017      TERM
6     55        1/24/2017     TEST5     30.74                   NEW
7     66        1/6/2017      TEST6     11.56                   NEW
8     66        1/19/2017     TEST7     -7.56     1/6/2017      TERM
13    88        1/5/2017      TEST12    -4.25     1/3/2017      TERM
16    99        1/16/2017     TEST15    -19.15    1/16/2017     TERM
17    99        1/24/2017     TEST16     19.15                   NEW
20    110       1/16/2017     TEST19    -21.86    1/16/2017      TERM
21    110       1/16/2017     TEST20     21.86                    NEW
24    1111      1/13/2017     TEST23     -7.36    1/13/2017      TERM
25    1111      1/18/2017     TEST24      8.14                    NEW
                              **TOTAL      -88.61**
```

Comment: why is row 16 kept when row 15 is it's negative? or 16 and 17.

Comment: Also: why rows 20 and 21 are kept while their sum is 0 for parentid=110?

Comment: Hi, 

Thank you for looking into this.
Actually there are multiple/duplicate transactions done by user, while i need to show one
trasactions.

Parentid = 99 
row 14 is term on same rate then row 15 is new add of same parent id on same rate them again 
row 16 is term on same rate, so parent id 99 actually terminated one time
id = 17, id 14 and 15 was dublication or mistaken entries whose sum of rate 
is zero (-19.15+19.15 = 0)

Comment: Similar case is with Parent id = 110
id = 18 terminate, id = 19 rehire , id = 20 terminate, id = 21 rehire 
rate for all four term rehire is same so two term and rehire trasaction is
done by user mistakenly. That's why I need to show only 1 term and new add.

Thanks,